# PHP finding a match eregi?

Tags: php, eregi

I have this code here

```
$search = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

The Search returns `Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Tablet; rv:14.0) Gecko/14.0 Firefox/14.0`

This find is inside an array

```
$find = '(Nexus 7) | ((Android) && (Tablet))';
```

This if statement is inside a foreach statement hence the break.

```
if(eregi($find, $search)) {
    break;
}else{
    $os = "Unknown";
}
```

and my if statment returns Unknown!! is there something wrong with my find string ((Android) && (Tablet)) or is eregi not what I want to use?

Comment: Eregi is deparacted. You should be using `preg_match()`.

Comment: Please note, as per the docs page on `eregi`: "This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged."

Comment: That isn't at all how regular expressions work. You can't use boolean operators like that.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using `strpos()` and an `if()` test:

```
if ( false !== strpos( $search, 'Nexus 7' ) ||
     ( false !== strpos( $search, 'Android' ) && 
       false !== strpos( $search, 'Tablet' ) ) { ... }
```

Note that the 'value-and-type' test (`!==`) must be used here because `strpos` will return '0' if the search term is found at the beginning of the target string.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!preg_match("/Nexus 7|Andriod|Tablet/", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) $os = "unknown";
```

Comment: Maybe you could revise your answer and give a little more information?

Comment: I would have went into more detail but only had a quick minute so just fixed the code :) I'll add the 'why' to the why this works when I get home, but you are correct, explaining the reasoning behind a solution is important - otherwise it's just copy & paste and nothing is learned